# MYSQL DB secure_connection

Tags: mysql, ssl, tls1.2

Is it possible to connect to mysql DB without SSL/TLS from client machine while "require_secure_transport=ON" in mysql setting ?

we tried to use useSSL=false from client end..

is it possible to bypass the above setting from mysql server from client and connect to DB

Comment: While MySQL version? Why do you have a `require_secure_transport` set and now want to connect insecurely?

Comment: Why not create a SSL authenticated client? Then it might be secure. How do you want it to be secure transport without SSL?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.